# In scipy why stats.kruskal can work with two populations?

Tags: wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test, kruskal-wallis-test

Krustall-wallis testing should be working only at least with 3 populations.But [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.kruskal.html), it seems to accept 2.

Krustall-wallis extends the Mann–Whitney U test, which is used for comparing only two groups.

So when you pass 2 populations, does it execute behind the [man-whitney](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.mannwhitneyu.html#scipy.stats.mannwhitneyu) test that should be the right testing for 2 groups ?

Is it correct to use Krustall test with only two groups in scipy ?

Comment: Kruskal-Wallais tests 2 or more groups, please read over the wiki article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kruskal–Wallis_one-way_analysis_of_variance